# how to reassign value to a variable after doing arithmetic operations in Django Template Language

Tags: python, html, django

I want to do arithmetic operations within Django Template format and also assign the new value to the same Variable

I have so far used {{with}} {{set}} and also django-mathfilters but i am unable to reassign value back to the same variable.

```html
                    {% with count=0 %}
                          {% for report in reports %}
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{{set count count|add:"1"}}</th>
                                <td>{{report.submit_time}}</td>
                                <td>{{report.file_name}}</td>
                                {% if report.is_complete %}
                                    <td>Complete</td>
                                {% else %}
                                    <td>Pending</td>
                                {% endif %}
                                <td>{{report.score}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {%endwith%}
```

i want to show numbers in serial in my table

Comment: You shouldn't need or want to assign in a template. What do you want to do with that `count` variable?

Comment: i want to show in my table as row 1... row 2 ... row 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to do any calculations here. Django provides you with a counter in every for loop.

```
<th scope="row">{{ forloop.counter }}</th>
```

(Note, you are using Django template language here, not Jinja2.)

Comment: Thank you so much for the solution. For further understanding i want to know if we can reassign a variable in DTL or why not ( if prohibited ). I am a beginner in Python and django.

Comment: No, templates are deliberately limited, and don't support that kind of operation.